# Xamarin.Forms publish and notice display update contents

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, clickonce

I am developing an Android application for PDAs using Xamarin.Forms and I have a few questions:

1. **How do you typically distribute your app after development?**
   In the case of Windows applications, I used ClickOnce, but it seems that Xamarin does not provide a service that can detect updated versions and request an update.
2. **How can I display update contents after an update?**
   After the update is complete, I would like to show the update contents with a checkbox such as "Do not show again" when the user enters the login screen. Would it be better to use a customized Alert or to display the update contents on a new page instead of a popup.

Currently, I am packaging the application as an APK file, signing it, and uploading it to the server. I have to tell customers to update the app every time a new version is released. I'm not sure what the best approach would be.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an application version in your apk, and while logging in you can send the login version as request parameter to verify if the app is latest build, if not show a pop up mentioning there is new apk available to download and navigate to where the users can download the apk from.